# Refund rules for a confirmed ticket vs non-confirmed ticket booked through Tatkal scheme of Indian railways

Tags: trains, tickets, india, refunds, tatkal

I have a few questions before I try to book a ticket through Tatkal scheme of Indian Railways:

1. I would like to know if I book a tatkaal ticket on irctc website for indian railways and I **do not get a confirm ticket**, can I get refund of the money?
2. Also if I happen to cancel a **confirmed tatkaal ticket**, is there any refund scheme?

Edit: I did check the [refund rules in the Indian railways website](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/refund_Rules.html) and I found out the following:

> No refund of fare shall be admissible on confirmed Tatkal ticket. 
>   In case of Tatkal ticket on **waitlist**, refund of fare shall be granted in
>   accordance with rule for unused waitlisted or RAC tickets.

So I guess the answer to my first question above is *yes* and the answer to the second question is *no* unless rules have changed recently and they are not yet documented.

But the second line of the quote above only mentions about waitlisted tatkaal tickets.

1. Is there no concept of RAC tickets through Tatkal scheme?
2. What does the rule for unused waitlisted or RAC tickets say? I would specifically like to know the rules for e-tickets as I am planning to do online booking only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know if I book a tatkaal ticket on irctc website for
>   indian railways and I do not get a confirm ticket, can I get refund of
>   the money?

Yes - Since you are not allocated a seat, entire amount is refunded (- service charges)

> Also if I happen to cancel a confirmed tatkaal ticket, is there any
>   refund scheme?

No - Even if you explicitly cancel, there wont be refund.

> Is there no concept of RAC tickets through Tatkal scheme?

No - Unlike normal bookings, Tatkal do no provision for RAC

> What does the rule for unused waitlisted or RAC tickets say? I would
>   specifically like to know the rules for e-tickets as I am planning to
>   do online booking only.

All Waitlist tickets are automatically cancelled and refunded

Comment: @S Rahul Bose Please correct me if I am wrong. So you are saying that for non-confirmed tickets even if I do not cancel the ticket, I will get a refund as the system will cancel it automatically?

Comment: Yes.  You need not worry about cancellation and refund issues.

Answer (score 3):

All the above answers provided are perfect, except the last part.

RAC tickets, for this purpose are considered confirmed tickets, and refund is provided accordingly, in this specific case though, RAC is not even possible in Tatkal.

However for tickets booked on-line and promoted to RAC (and even without a confirmed sleeping berth) at the time of charting is considered as confirmed and no refund would be provided if you don't travel. This is completely different from the treatment of wait-listed tickets booked on-line for which refund is provided automatically.

Please note these two points from (http://www.indianrail.gov.in/refund_Rules.html)

> In case of e-tickets (confirmed or RAC), if the reservation charts have been prepared, online TDR is required to be filed for obtaining refund. No refund of fare shall be admissible on e- ticket having confirmed reservation in case the request for refund is filed online after two hours of the actual departure of the train.

And

> No refund of fare shall be admissible on RAC e-tickets in case the request for refund is filed online after three hours of the actual departure of the train.

Comment: Done! I actually thought I added it already thanks for the edits in the previous question, most of them silly mistakes